# unexpected use of comma using map on a object

Tags: javascript, eslint, airbnb-js-styleguide

I'm using the AirBnb style guide and get an "unexpected use of comma" error here at the end of the first line of code:

```
  myApp.fields.map(field => (field.obj.label = field.label.default,
    field.label.textContent = field.obj.label));
```

I can rewrite it to this to remove the error:

```
  myApp.fields.map(field => field.obj.label = field.label.default);
  myApp.fields.map(field => field.label.textContent = field.obj.label);
```

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-sequences

The way I see the first bit of code that the map loop only runs once of the fields where the second one runs twice.

I can confirm that both parts of the map above are executing and not just the last one. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: 1) ESLint specifies the general rule, why would it specifically list `map()`? 2) Why are you using map if you're not transforming the array?

Comment: use forEach then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not transforming the array, you could just use `forEach()` instead of `map()`. If you insist on making it into a one-liner, and don't want to violate the no-sequences rule:

```
myApp.fields.forEach(field => {field.obj.label = field.label.default; field.label.textContent = field.obj.label});
```

More readable:

```
myApp.fields.forEach((field) => {
    field.obj.label = field.label.default;
    field.label.textContent = field.obj.label;
});
```

Comment: Thanks that works but with it gives error "Expected parentheses around arrow function argument having a body with curly braces. (arrow-parens)". Needs brackets around the field ex. (field), if you want to add that to your answer I'll check it